# Remove Duplicates in Array and update refering indices. (Remove Duplicate Vertices and Faces)

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, graphics, 3d

i need to find a fast way to remove duplicate vertices and faces of a mesh.

The vertices and faces are stored in a Buffers, because I'm working with large data sets I use `boost::shared_array<float> vertexBuffer` and `boost::shared_array<float> faceBuffer` for the Buffers. 
Next I create a KD-Search-Tree and check for each point if it has a neighbour with `dist(point, neighbour)<tollerance`. If a neighbour is found i map the neigbour index to the point index in a `unordered_map`:

`oldToNewID[neighbour_id]=point_id`

Now i would like to move all vertices that are stored as value in the map to the end of the vertexbuffer. The problem here is that I need to also change the ID of the Face - Points.

For example:

VertexBuffer:

```
          1.3 4.5 3.7|1.8 4.5 3.7|1.3 4.5 3.7|4.3 8.5 2.7|4.9 4.5 2.7
          -----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
            Vertex 0    Vertex 1    Vertex 2    Vertex 3    Vertex 4
```

FaceBuffer:

```
          0 1 3   |   1 2 3   |   4 0 1   |   2 3 4 
      ------------------------------------------------
          Face 0  |   Face 1  |   Face 2  |   Face 3
```

Now Vertex 0 and Vertex 2 are duplicate. So now i somehow have to change the VertexBuffer and FaceBuffer efficiantly so that i will result in:

Updated VertexBuffer:

```
          1.3 4.5 3.7|1.8 4.5 3.7|4.3 8.5 2.7|4.9 4.5 2.7|1.3 4.5 3.7
          -----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------
            Vertex 0    Vertex 1    Vertex 3    Vertex 4    Vertex 2
            NewID  0    NewID  1    NewID  2    NewID  3
```

Updated FaceBuffer:

```
          0 1 2   |   1 0 2   |   3 0 1   |   0 2 3 
      ------------------------------------------------
          Face 0  |   Face 1  |   Face 2  |   Face 3
```

The duplicates should be moved to the back of the buffer and the faces that where referencing to Vertex 2 needed to be changed. Also each face refering to Vertex 3 and Vertex 4 must be updated because they changed their position.

Any Ideas how to realise that?

Thanks alot!

Comment: Why do you need to move the vertex to the end? I would think that operation would be unnecessarily expensive given a large array.

Comment: Because creating a new Vertex-Array and inserting all none duplicate vertices would result in allocating a lot of new memory, which might exceed the amount of memory availible.

Comment: So at the end of the day you want to pass these arrays to some rendering engine?

Comment: almost. After i removed the duplicate vertices and faces i run some simplification algorithms on the mesh (which don't work well with duplicate vertices and faces) after all that it can be redered.

Comment: Ok, why can't you just change the vertex indices in the faces array, pass these and the (as is) vertex array to the simplification algorithms? The simplification algorithm should only care about the connectivity (topology) of vertices represented in the faces. Those vertices in the array that are duplicates will simply not be referenced in this process. Finally, you should also be able to pass the vertex array as is to the renderer. Again, those vertices not referenced by the geometry will not be "used."

Comment: To add to my last comment, to remove duplicate faces (i.e., faces that end up with the same referenced vertices), you should consider using `shared_ptr<std::vector<float>>` instead. Then you can use all the `std::vector` capabilities to `erase` a range of faces.